# Bundling typescript with RollUp - Couldn't process compiler options

Tags: javascript, typescript, bundler, rollupjs

I'm trying to bundle my typescript files RollUp (https://rollupjs.org/)
I used this configuration files:

rollup.config.js:

```
import alias from 'rollup-plugin-alias';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript';
import angular from 'rollup-plugin-angular';

export default {
    entry: '../main.ts',
    format: 'iife',
    dest: 'dist/bundle.es2015.js',
    sourceMap: true,
    plugins: [
        angular(),
        typescript(),
        alias({ rxjs: __dirname + '/node_modules/rxjs-es' }),
        resolve({
            jsnext: true,
            main: true,
            browser: true
        })
    ],
    external: [
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/router-deprecated'
    ],
    globals: {
        '@angular/common': 'vendor._angular_common',
        '@angular/compiler': 'vendor._angular_compiler',
        '@angular/core': 'vendor._angular_core',
        '@angular/http': 'vendor._angular_http',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'vendor._angular_platformBrowser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'vendor._angular_platformBrowserDynamic',
        '@angular/router': 'vendor._angular_router',
        '@angular/forms': 'vendor._angular_forms'
    }
}
```

vendor.js:

```
import * as _angular_common from '@angular/common';
import * as _angular_compiler from '@angular/compiler';
import * as _angular_core from '@angular/core';
import * as _angular_http from '@angular/http';
import * as _angular_platformBrowser from '@angular/platform-browser';
import * as _angular_platformBrowserDynamic from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import * as _angular_router from '@angular/router';
import * as _angular_forms from '@angular/forms';

export default {
    _angular_common,
    _angular_compiler,
    _angular_core,
    _angular_http,
    _angular_platformBrowser,
    _angular_platformBrowserDynamic,
    _angular_router,
    _angular_forms
};
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
rollup-plugin-typescript: Argument for '--target' option must be 'ES3', 'ES5', or 'ES2015'.
rollup-plugin-typescript: Unknown compiler option 'lib'.
rollup-plugin-typescript: Couldn't process compiler options
```

What am I doing wrong? (I'm new at this so if I'm didn't write some needed information  - please tell me)

## EDIT:

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": ".\\Compiled-JS\\Apps\\Client",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Comment: what's your tsconfig.json? - also does this work when `typescript({ tsconfig: false })`?

Comment: @DenisTsoi: I added my tsconfig.json... When I use tsconfig: false - I get a "unexpected character '@'" error as if it doesn't know it's typescript (because of the "@NgModule" of angular 2).

Comment: also are you using https://github.com/ezolenko/rollup-plugin-typescript2?

Comment: Change the target from es2017 to es2015 also lib option may not be supported in rollup-plugin-typescript

Comment: the rollup-plugin-typescript2 worked! If you post this as an answer I'll "accept" it. thanks :)

Comment: awesome! glad it helped - so did changing the target help or was it just using typescript2 help?

Comment: It was the typescript2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may need to use [rollup-plugin-typescript2](http://github.com/ezolenko/rollup-plugin-typescript2).

Rollup-plugin-typescript seems to support 1.8.9 as default, which may also be a part of the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution **without switching to `rollup-plugin-typescript-2`.**

Turns out (bearing in mind the problem described in Denis Tsoi's answer) all you need to do is pass `rollup-plugin-typescript` your own locally installed version of Typescript as follows:

```
import ts from 'rollup-plugin-typescript';
import typescript from 'typescript'


const config = {
  plugins: [
    ts({
      typescript
    })
  ]
};

export default config;
```

Original solution can be found here:

https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-typescript/issues/114#issuecomment-399100699

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the rollup-plugin-typescript-2 runs into other errors, for which there is practically no documentation (at the time of writing this post).

So, without switching the rollup plugin, I got past this error by fixing the tsconfig.json compilerOptions. I had the `include` property in the wrong place. I finally understood that the error refers to an unsupported or incorrect property in the compilerOptions inside tsconfig.json. See the discussion [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/161#issuecomment-643856686) for examples of supported property values. For example, it also seems that `module: commonjs` isn't supported at the moment.

For instance, supported values for `target` and `module`

```
"target": "ES2015 (or greater)",
"module": "ES2015, ES2020, or ESNEXT"
```

Answer (score 0):

The rollup plugin has been updated and now uses whatever version of typescript you've installed as a peer dependency.